# Access 'coarse_label' in CIFAR-100 loaded from tensorflow_datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm loading the CIFAR-100 using tensorflow_datasets [(tfds doc)](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/cifar100)

```
train, test = tfds.load(name="cifar100:3.*.*", split=["train", "test"], as_supervised=True)
```

CIFAR-100 has both a label (100 classes) as well as a coarse_label (20 classes) as shown in the doc linked above. It's easy to access the label, e.g.:

```
for image, label in train:
     # ... the label here is the actual label, not the coarse_label
```

However, I am planning to do operations based on the coarse_label, e.g., to filter by it or to use it as a label in a Keras classifier.

How can I access the coarse_label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If I don't load as supervised, i.e., if I remove `as_supervised=True`

```
train, test = tfds.load(name="cifar100:3.*.*", split=["train", "test"])
```

, I can get the coarse_labels from the dictionaries, e.g.

```
for item in train:
   print(item['coarse_label'])
```

Like this, I will be able to remodel the dataset s.t. the coarse_labels can be used for classification. However, it still looks quite unnatural to me that I have to load `as_supervised=False` even though I'm interested in the labels. If anyone has a better solution, I'm happy to accept that answer.